# Passing i+1 or some other arithmetic as an arg

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a situation where I am using an if statement in a for loop and need to check the current iteration and the next iteration for a condition.

Currently I have:

```
For i = 1 To Len(inLine)
        If Asc(Mid(inLine, i, 1)) = 10 And dnl = False Then
            dnl = True
            outLine = outLine + " "
        ElseIf Asc(Mid(inLine, i, 1)) = 10 And dnl = True Then
            dnl = False
            outLine = outLine & ">" & vbNewLine & "<"
        Else
            dnl = False
            outLine = outLine & Mid(inLine, i, 1)
        End If
Next
```

In the file I am parsing through, there are areas where a double newline is used to separate blocks of texts. These newlines aren't always readable though. For instance, when the file is read, the whole file is put into `inline` even though there are newlines included.

Basically, I want to add a space where a single newline char is found and add a `vbNewLine` where a double is found. So I tried this:

```
If Asc(Mid(inLine, i, 1)) = 10 And Asc(Mid(inLine, (i + 1), 1)) = 10 Then
```

When stepping through the program, this seems to work, but when the code finishes, I get a run-time error `Invalid procedure call or argument`.

I have tried taking out the parenthesis, using i = i + 1, i++, all to no avail. I have tried searching a way to use arithmetic as an argument and haven't been able to find what I am looking for. Is there a way to do this? Is there a different way to check the next iteration ahead of the for loop?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mid with `i + 1` will error on the last loop as `i + 1` is referring to a character beyond the end of the string.  You will need to do something to keep it from falling off the end of the string.

Use Application.Min to ensure the end is found:

```
If Asc(Mid(inLine, i, 1)) = 10 And Asc(Mid(inLine, Application.Min(i + 1,Len(inLine)), 1)) = 10 Then
```

Comment: This works unless the end of the line is a newline which it would then add two newlines to the end as the condition would read true twice. For my situation this is not a problem though as I am searching through for content so as long as I can read each line I am good. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, with `i+1` you will reference an unexisting index once you reach the end of the string.

But there are easier ways to accomplish what you want, using `Replace`. If your input string does not have double spaces, nor trailing spaces at the start or end of a line, then:

```
 outline = Replace(Replace(inline, vbLf, " "), "  ", vbLf)
```

If these conditions are not true in your case, you can first fix those issues with some other `Replace` calls.

Comment: The problem with this is some of them I want to replace with a space whereas others with a new line. I also tried the replace function before and it didn't recognize all of the newlines for some reason. (The newlines were created in a python program so I'm wondering if it used different encoding for different spots)

Comment: In your question you wrote that you want to replace double newlines by single newlines, and single newlines by spaces. That is what is happening here if the condition I mentioned is true. Note the double space near the end. Of course, if you are not sure of the characters that make the newline, then you need to inspect that first. Should not be difficult to do.

Comment: This would probably be a good solution but somehow the encoding of the text isn't recognized as a vbLf, vbCr, or a vbNewLine. The only way I was able to isolate it is by finding the ASCII value, which corresponds to a newline but isn't read as such, compare it and replace it myself. Thank you for your help on this though.